# Render problem error message in XML Design view when use GridLayout

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

I am using a GridLayout inside ConstrainLayout. Only 1 column and 5 rows in it.

Everything working properly in real and virtual device how I want it but there is an error message in the XML/design view.

The message:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO7MW.jpg)

Render problem, View draw failed, try refresh the layout.

How can fix it?

If I delete the GridLayout the error gone.

I tried delete the views inside the layout individually but the problem still there.

from xml:

```
<GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridlyMiddle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:rowCount="5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guidelinev50"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guidelinev60"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

from gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
}
```

Comment: what error is it ?

Comment: [error](https://i.imgur.com/Vd269Lt.jpg)